# Origin of contigo and similar "contractions"

Tags: etimología

What's the history of the words *contigo*, *conmigo*, etc?

They're treated like contractions for *con ti* and *con mi*, respectively, but they actually make the word *longer* rather than shorter, as contractions ought to do.

It occurs to me that there are a whole host of other words in Spanish that have similar spellings and functions (*amigo*, *enemigo*, etc) , how do they fit into this puzzle?

Are *ti* and *mi* shortened versions of previously used pronouns *tigo* and *migo*, or something?  This would make the meaning of *amigo* clear: *a-* (not) *migo* (me)

Comment: Not worthy of its own answer but - the two first Google results for "conmigo etimología" point to the same direction: the latin form *mecum*.

Comment: I believe it's in part a vestigial remnant of Latin's case system.

Comment: These forms have always intrigued me. The Latin derivation obviously springs to mind. But the "mig-" stuff looks Germanic to me (mich in German, mig in Swedish, meg in Norwegian etc). Could this be a remnant of Gothic?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's a good answer [here](http://blog.lengua-e.com/2007/origen-de-conmigo/) in Spanish. Basically, in Latin it was said:

*mecum* = *me* + *cum* (mí + con)

The *cum* was being lost, evolving into a *go* (*migo*). To reinforce the lost *con*, it was added at the beginning:

*con* + *migo* = *conmigo*

Comment: `Latin` *me* + *cum* > *mecum* > *micu(m)* > *migo* > ***con*** + *migo* > *conmigo* `Spanish`

Answer (score 7):

They are not contractions because there is not a "long form" to say the same.
*Conti* and *conmi* do not exist.

They come from latin:

- cum: with
- mecum: with me
- tecum: with you

Amigo and enemigo come from latin too (amicus, inimicus) but I think they are not related to *mecum*.

Comment: And I'm positive "contraction" has such a fixed definition. I'll have to look it up.

Answer (score 6):

The full history of these words is somewhat interesting (to me at least). If you will indulge a somewhat long explanation ...

If we go back around 5000 years, our linguistic ancestors, the Proto-IndoEuropeans were living Western/Southwestern Asia. Their language, PIE, was a very sophisticated language, very different from anything that exists today, though many features of the language have survived.

One interesting aspect of PIE was that there was nothing like "prepositions" as they exist today. So, for example, in the English sentence "Go with me", the verb is "go" and the prepositional phrase "with me" modifies it. The pronoun "me" is the object of "with". In PIE, it was distinctly different. The pronoun would be the object of the verb: "Go me". The "with" would be what is called a particle word, which gives context to the relationship between "go" and "me". Word order in PIE (as with Latin, Ancient Greek, Sanskrit, and many other ancient languages) was much more free than in many modern languages, because of inflections in the nouns, pronouns, and verbs. So for this phrase the word order could look like "me go with", "with go me", "go me with", or other variations. There would be no loss of clarity. And again, the "with" would not be associated with "me" alone but would be associated with "me" and "go".

In PIE, the word for "me" was *hme (or *me depending on which scholar you ask). The word for "with" was *kom. In Latin these words became "me" and "cum", respectively. What appears to have been the case, at least for the PIE ancestors that reached Italy, was that placing *kom after *hme (and other accusative pronouns) was especially common. In other words, "*hme *kom", "*te *kom", etc. would be the most common word ordering. It was, in fact, so common that it stuck in Latin: "me cum", "te cum", etc.

Now, what is interesting here is that, in Latin, the concept of particle words virtually disappeared entirely (whereas they still exist to a great degree in German, English, and some other languages). In Latin these particles changed into strict prepositions and adverbs (in most cases). So the particle word *kom became the preposition "cum". And as with all prepositions in Latin, all prepositional objects of "cum" come AFTER the preposition. So logically "with me" should be "cum me". However, as mentioned, the word order "me cum" was highly ingrained in Latin from its ancient history, despite this violating the prepositional rule. So what happened in Latin was that "me cum" became an adverb "mecum" (and similarly "tecum", "nobiscum", etc.). By making it a single word, there was no violation of the prepositional rule. Hence these odd little adverbs that existed in Latin throughout Antiquity.

Then we come to Late Antiquity and the early Middle Ages. The Western Roman Empire has brought in huge numbers of foreign tribes, the Goths in particular, to man its armies and perform other functions that the Romans do not want to do. Although these tribes live in the Empire, they are not granted citizenship and are segregated from the Romans themselves. They learn Latin, but very bad Latin. Some scholars have described the language they developed as a "creole" of Latin and Gothic, i.e. inspired by Latin but not really Latin. These tribes eventually overthrew their Roman masters and hence we have the Middle Ages. The languages that emerged in much of Europe really evolved from this "creole", not really Latin proper. In this creole, there were many rapid changes to the language, some uniform, some regional. One that occurred was that, because "mecum" seemed to violate the standard rules of Latin, the Iberians hypercorrected this to "cum mecum" ("with me-with"). But, of course, as that was not quite right either that quickly became a single word, "cum-mecum". And then, as the Iberian languages evolved, this became "conmigo".

Hope that wasn't too long-winded.

Comment: Fascinating.  Thanks!  Gives me more respect for Creole / mishmash languages.

Comment: Fascinating. Do you have any sources?

Comment: I'll have to track down sources. I doubt you'll find this little history in any single source. This is assembled from having read a number of different sources in the past.

Comment: A few quick Wiki articles that address a tiny bit of this: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mecum; https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/conmigo; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Indo-European_particles; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Indo-European_pronouns

Comment: Some other stuff: http://etimologias.dechile.net/?conmigo

Comment: A few more authoritative sources that discuss some of this:
https://indo-european.info/WebHelp/8_particles.htm (discusses PIE particles);
The Oxford Introduction to Proto-Indo-European and the Proto-Indo-European World, pg 290, https://books.google.com/books?id=iNUSDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA290 (talks about derivation of cum from *kom)

Comment: A couple more authoritative sources:
A Comprehensive Etymological Dictionary of the Spanish Language, pg 406, https://books.google.com/books?id=ex1wAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA406 (shows derivation of conmigo from Latin);
Language Change and Language Contact in Pidgins and Creoles, pg 107-109, 122, https://books.google.com/books?id=Pcc9AAAAQBAJ&pg=PA107 (discusses the dramatic changes from Latin to Romance and the theory that this was a creolization process)