# Conmigo, contigo, consigo... connusco, convusco?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, pronombres, dialectos, español-medieval, arcaísmos

In addition to the pronouns *conmigo, contigo, consigo* there are the antiquated forms [*connusco*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=AMV39kS), and [*convusco*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Ahsw0Bz).

These forms have been seen as outdated since at least as far back as 1611<sup>1</sup>, having competed with the forms *con nos*, *con vos* since the 14th century<sup>2</sup>.

However, in the Stevens' *"A New Spanish and English Dictionary"* (1706), the author notes that these forms were still in use in some regional sociolects:

> ***Conúſco,*** Obſ. with us. Us'd in ſome parts by Peaſants.
>
> ***Convúſco,*** Obſ. with you. Us'd only by ſome Peaſants.

**In what regions/dialects were these forms used at this time, and, are they still used today?**

---

<sup>1. *Rosal* (1611):</sup>  <sup>*"**Conosco ò Conusco.** decia el antiguo Castell. para decir con nosotros;"*</sup>
<sup>2. [Excessive Analogical Change as an Impetus for Lexical Loss: Old Spanish *Connusco*, *Convusco*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/27940047.pdf?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)</sup>
<sup>3. [*Convusco:* a casualty of analogy, or of differential “(un)fitness”?](https://www.degruyter.com/view/j/ling.1997.35.issue-1/ling.1997.35.1.57/ling.1997.35.1.57.xml)</sup>

Comment: **Note:** I suspect the answer will include at least Galicia, since in modern Galician and Portuguese the forms [*connosco*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/connosco) and [*convosco*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/convosco) are still used.

Comment: On a related topic it would be interesting to know why the Latin mecum became conmigo and so on.

Comment: @mdewey [Origin of contigo and similar “contractions”](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/74/origin-of-contigo-and-similar-contractions) this may also be of interest: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mecum#Etymology

Comment: La recompensa terminó sin candidato a otorgársela :(

Answer (score 2):

The following paper analyses the geographical spread of these terms:

> #### 5.2. Distribución geográfica
>
> ...
>
> [image]
>
> En el Mapa 1 podemos ver que las formas *connusco* y *convusco* son claramente
>   las predominantes en el siglo XIII, tal y como hemos comentado en la cronología. Las provincias con más ocurrencias de las variantes sintéticas son Valladolid, Burgos y León. Estas dos últimas, además, también presentan formas de con nos y con vos. En concreto, un 20% (bastante por encima de la media de este siglo) y un 9.5% respectivamente. Además, aunque tengan un bajo número de ocurrencias, es necesario destacar la presencia de con nos y con vos en Cantabria, Álava y La Rioja, de modo que, según nuestros datos, las variantes analíticas simples se concentran en el norte de la península ibérica, especialmente en las provincias más próximas a Navarra.
>
> Sin embargo, el problema con el que nos encontramos en este siglo es que hay
>   muchas provincias sin representar. Es decir, que los documentos de estas áreas no
>   contienen ocurrencias de los pronombres estudiados. De este modo, nuestros datos
>   quedan incompletos al no tener textos de Navarra, Huesca, Zaragoza y Teruel, provincias en las que esperaríamos un mayor número de apariciones de *con nos* y *con vos*. Sería necesario ampliar el corpus para cubrir la zona oriental y poder llegar a una conclusión sobre el origen de estas formas.
>
> ...
>
> Tal y como hemos dicho unas páginas antes, ***connusco* y *convusco* no vuelven a aparecer después de 1448,** por lo que en el siglo XVI (ver Mapa 4) solo encontramos *con nos/con vos* y *con nosotros/con vosotros*.
>
> - [*Estudio diacrónico y diatópico de la evolución histórica de connusco y convusco en castellano*](https://dspace.uib.es/xmlui/bitstream/handle/11201/146624/tfm_2015-16_MLL2_mga362_374.pdf?sequence=1), Universitat de les Illes Balears (2016)