# Why do we use "conmigo" but not "sinmigo"?

Tags: etimología, historia, preposiciones, neologismos, contracciones

In Spanish we typically use *"conmigo"* for "with me" but *"sin mí"* for "without me".

What are the origins of the word *"conmigo*"? How did it come to be preferred over *"con mí"*? Why do we continue to prefer *"sin mí"* over something like *"sinmigo"*?

Comment: Here in Argentina we once had a poorly educated union leader called Herminio Iglesias who made the gross mistake in an election speech, "conmigo o sinmigo". He became notorious, among other things, for that blunder. https://elpais.com/diario/2007/02/24/agenda/1172271606_850215.html

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### [Origin of *conmigo*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/74/origin-of-contigo-and-similar-contractions/)

In Latin, "with me" was expressed *mecum* ("mí con"). Over time this word evolved phonologically to the point where the original "with" sense needed to be reinforced:<sup>1</sup>

*me**cum**→ micu(m) → migo → **con**migo*

Since the "-go" comes from *cum* ("con"), there was no parallel path for [***sine** me*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sine#Latin) ("sin mí") to evolve into something like **sinmigo*.<sup>2</sup>

A similar process happened with *cada quisque* (lit. "cada cada uno").

### *Sinmigo* in contemporary Spanish

However, given that *conmigo* is lexicalised in Spanish, it has been hypothesized that analogous forms **sinmigo, *sintigo* etc may develop:

> In conclusion, we might speculate on the future of the lexemes *conmigo, contigo, consigo*. Will they eventually follow [*connusco, convusco*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/27465/conmigo-contigo-consigo-connusco-convusco) and regularize to *con mí, con ti, con sí*, or will the pressures of the language academies preserve them with the apparently meaningless morpheme *-go*? Or will this morpheme spread through lexical polarization, i.e., *conmigo ~ *sin migo*, *contigo ~ *sin tigo*, and then on to other syntagmas, **de migo, *de tigo, *a migo, *a tigo*, etc.?<sup>10</sup> Unfortunately for diachronists of the present, only time will tell.
>
> - [*Excessive Analogical Change as an Impetus for Lexical Loss: Old Spanish* connusco, convusco](https://www.jstor.org/stable/27940047?seq=1) (1990)

And indeed this has been noted in [some Argentinian and Mexican speakers](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/sinmigo-sintigo-sinsigo.395582/) (though this is heavily stigmatised):

> Pues en México, se oye "sinmigo" y "sintigo" pero también se oye ["haiga."](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=haber)
>
> Es usado, pero no correcto.

This is not to be confused with its use ironically (e.g. ["Sinmigo"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f6EAeasF0sM)).

---

1. This is known as a pleonasm (or *datismo*). This example can be considered a positive analogue of the [Jespersen's Cycle](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/27614/etymology-of-nada-and-nadie/27618#27618).
2. Why Latin *cum mē* was replaced by the form *mēcum* has [multiple proposed explanations](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mecum#Etymology).

- https://revistas.ucm.es/index.php/RFRM/article/download/63507/4564456549390

Answer (score 22):

The preposition "con" (with) comes from the Latin preposition "cum" and in that language when using pronouns, they would put "cum" at the end so instead of saying "cum me" they would say "mecum" (with me), tecum (with you), etc. Over time, people who spoke vulgar Latin started saying "cum mecum" to say "with me" which evolved to become "conmigo" in Spanish. We also have "contigo" (with you) and "consigo",although this last one is only used with the word "mismo" (self) in sentences like "él se enojó consigo mismo" (he got mad at himself), "ella estaba hablando consigo misma" (she was talking to herself).

On the other hand, "sin" comes from "sine" (without) and it was always put before the pronoun in Latin, "sine me" (without me), "sine te" (without you) and it became "sin mí", "sin ti". Although I've heard young teenagers saying "sinmigo" and "sintigo" a couple of times before but in a playful manner, completely aware that it was wrong.

Comment: In fact, Dante used *meco, teco, seco, nosco, vosco* when writing in Italian.